# ReSTful web service to send and receive soap+xml

Tags: wcf, rest

I am writing a **RESTful web service** and have a big trouble in getting the basic step up itself.

I could do the below:

1. Could create RESTful web service and send and receive the XML (not soap+xml) back to the client with `webHttpBinding`
2. Could create RESTful web service and send and receive the soap+xml using the contract as defined below:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]        
        XmlElement PostRequestXML(Stream xmlData);
   ```

Is the point (2) is right way to send and receive the soap+xml data?

I did a lots of search on web, but could not find better link which explains the detailed steps on creating web service to send and receive soap+xml.

I would like to know :

- what is better way to design my RESTful web service to send and receive soap+xml? Can you show me operation contract definition?
- which binding do I need to use? SHare if any example.

  - can you share me the detailed information on writing `OperationContract` and configuring web.config?

The request and respond should like as below.

REQUEST:

```
Header:
 POST /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc HTTP/1.1
 Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
 User-Agent: Windows Phone 8 Enrollment Client
 Host: EnterpriseEnrollment.Contoso.com
 Content-Length: xxx
 Cache-Control: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
 xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <s:Header>
 <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/IDiscoveryService/Discover
 </a:Action>
 <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</a:MessageID>
 <a:ReplyTo>
 <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
 </a:ReplyTo>
 <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">
https://ENROLLTEST.CONTOSO.COM/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc
 </a:To>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body>
 <Discover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/">
 <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <EmailAddress>user@contoso.com</EmailAddress>
 <RequestVersion>1.0</RequestVersion>
 </request>
 </Discover>
 </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE:

Header:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Length: 865
 Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
 Server: EnterpriseEnrollment.Contoso.com
 Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2012 00:32:56 GMT



<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
 <s:Header>
 <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/IDiscoveryService/DiscoverResponse
 </a:Action>
 <ActivityId>
 d9eb2fdd-e38a-46ee-bd93-aea9dc86a3b8
 </ActivityId>
 <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</a:RelatesTo>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">>
 <DiscoverResponse
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment">
 <DiscoverResult>
 <AuthPolicy>OnPremise</AuthPolicy>
 <AuthUrl/>
 <EnrollmentPolicyServiceUrl>
https://enrolltest.contoso.com/ENROLLMENTSERVER/DEVICEENROLLMENTWEBSERVICE.SVC
 </EnrollmentPolicyServiceUrl>
 <EnrollmentServiceUrl>
https://enrolltest.contoso.com/ENROLLMENTSERVER/DEVICEENROLLMENTWEBSERVICE.SVC
 </EnrollmentServiceUrl>
 <FederatedServiceName/>
 <FederatedServicePolicy/>
 </DiscoverResult>
 </DiscoverResponse>
 </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I can't give an example right now (no time), but you can use option 2 and expose to endpoints for your service - for example a WebHttpBinding (for REST) and a BasicHttpBinding (for SOAP).  Google should give plenty of examples on how to do this.

Comment: Creating two different points requires use of two different addresses, but the protocol uses the same URI for both GET and POST. How can I use same URI with two different end points?

Comment: the funny thing is in your #2 you aren't specifying a template Uri so how can it even be RESTful!  :)  The whole point of rest is to expose Uri templates and that means here you'd need to put in something, so I don't even see how this is close to being RESTful.  I see that a lot in WCF where people think they are creating something RESTful yet they don't even specify a Uri, that makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

I have created many WCF API, some of them are REST.
My main understanding is - don't use it!
WCF is good in enabling you to choose the type of protocol to use between server and client.
Using it you pay in performance and durability.
If you already set your mind on REST (which is an excellent choice) I suggest you dig into [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/). This is by far the most mature, maintained and advanced REST framework for .NET
It is easy to use and helps you build the API correctly, by making many smart choices on the way.
Give it a shot and never look back!

Comment: The Microsoft Mobile Device Management protocol says that I need to implement RESTful web services. Because the some part of web service client is written by Microsoft.